# CSS Border-length Control w/o Div

Tags: html, css, styles, border

I have a border that goes around a super short two line text above a picture that is width 500px and height 400px. Is there a way to control the length of the border so it is only 500px in length to make it line up just above the picture? Im not using div and i have tried border-length: 500px but that isnt working and when I tired border-width: 500px it just messed it up. I just want the border around the text to be the same length as the picture to make it look cleaner. (I also know there is probably a lot cleaner way of doing the style then what I have, but I would like to try and keep it in the format I have if possible!) Thank you in advance!!

```css
h2.border {
  border-top: 3px dotted #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #e5e5e5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, inset 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, 0 -1px 0 0 #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

h3.border {
  border-top: 3px dotted #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #e5e5e5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, inset 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, 0 -1px 0 0 #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

h4.dotted {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-length: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow39.js"></script>

<BODY bgColor="#87CEFA">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <section id="top area">
      <article class="box-right">
        <form action="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/search.php" method="post">
          <Center>
            <h2 class="border"> Search for Content</h2>
            <p>
              <label>Category (Dog, cat, Hamster):</label>
              <input name="category" placeholder="Dog, cat, hamster" type="text">
            </p>
            <!-- Changed Animal type to Animal size(animal_size)-->
            <p>
              <label>Animal size (Large, Small, Small, Tiny/Dawf):</label>
              <input name="animal_size" placeholder="Dawf Hamster" type="text">
            </p>
            <p>
              <input value="Submit" type="submit">
            </p>
            <a href="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/FinalPro_Main.html">
     Return to Main page </a>
            </br>
            <h3 class="border"> Pictures of a few animals we have right now</h3>
            <h4 class="dotted"> Large Dog </br> Name: Tiny</h4>
            <img src="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/bigdog.jpg" alt="Big Dog" Style="width:500px;height:400px;"></br>
            <h4 class="dotted"> Small Dog </br> Name: Yippy</h4>
            <img src="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/smalldog.jpg" alt="Small Dog" Style="width:400px;height:600px;"></br>
            <h4 class="dotted"> Small Cat </br> Name: Teddy</h4>
            <img src="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/smallcat.jpeg" alt="Small Cat" Style="width:400px;height:600px;"></br>
            <h4 class="dotted"> Small Hamster </br> Name: Digger</h4>
            <img src="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/dawfhamster.jpg" alt="Small hamster" Style="width:400px;height:600px;">
            </br>
            </br>
            <a href="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/FinalPro_Main.html">
    Return to Main page </a>
          </center>
        </form>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Will all your images be of the same width? Because I see that your second and third images are not 500px.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using `width: 500px;` instead of `border-`whatever? Also, are you wanting all of these header texts to have the same width? Because it looks like your second, third, and fourth picture are all different widths than the first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need to control is the size of the container for the text. That way the border will take just that space, since you have a fixed `width` on your imgs you can do the same for the container and use auto margin to keep the center:

```css
h2.border {
  border-top: 3px dotted #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #e5e5e5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, inset 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, 0 -1px 0 0 #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

h3.border {
  border-top: 3px dotted #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #e5e5e5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, inset 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5, 0 -1px 0 0 #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

h4.dotted {
  border-style: dotted;
  max-width:500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow39.js"></script>

<BODY bgColor="#87CEFA">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <section id="top area">
      <article class="box-right">
        <form action="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/search.php" method="post">
          <Center>
            <h2 class="border"> Search for Content</h2>
            <p>
              <label>Category (Dog, cat, Hamster):</label>
              <input name="category" placeholder="Dog, cat, hamster" type="text">
            </p>
            <!-- Changed Animal type to Animal size(animal_size)-->
            <p>
              <label>Animal size (Large, Small, Small, Tiny/Dawf):</label>
              <input name="animal_size" placeholder="Dawf Hamster" type="text">
            </p>
            <p>
              <input value="Submit" type="submit">
            </p>
            <a href="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/FinalPro_Main.html">
     Return to Main page </a>
            </br>
            <h3 class="border"> Pictures of a few animals we have right now</h3>
            <h4 class="dotted"> Large Dog </br> Name: Tiny</h4>
            <img src="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/bigdog.jpg" alt="Big Dog" Style="width:500px;height:400px;"></br>
            <h4 class="dotted"> Small Dog </br> Name: Yippy</h4>
            <img src="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/smalldog.jpg" alt="Small Dog" Style="width:400px;height:600px;"></br>
            <h4 class="dotted"> Small Cat </br> Name: Teddy</h4>
            <img src="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/smallcat.jpeg" alt="Small Cat" Style="width:400px;height:600px;"></br>
            <h4 class="dotted"> Small Hamster </br> Name: Digger</h4>
            <img src="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/dawfhamster.jpg" alt="Small hamster" Style="width:400px;height:600px;">
            </br>
            </br>
            <a href="http://sarahmcintosh.x10host.com/Sarah%20McIntosh%20CS0334/Lab%20Assignments/Lab%2010/Lab%2010/FinalPro_Main.html">
    Return to Main page </a>
          </center>
        </form>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That works!! Sweet Thank you so much!!! It was driving me crazy that i couldnt figure it out!

Comment: Glad to help U @SarahMcIntosh don't forget to mark your question as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve a border of 500px using this :

```
h4.dotted {
  border-style: dotted;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

Does that solve your issue? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Is there a way to control the length of the border so it is only 500px
>   in length to make it line up just above the picture?

Assuming that you want that box to be 500px wide, do this for your `h4.dotted`:

```
h4.dotted {
  border-style: dotted;
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```